# C++ - Template template parameter with default argument doesn't work

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-templates

So I have a class of the form:

```
template <typename T, template <typename T> class Container = std::vector>
class MyArray : Container<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Now I'm trying to instantiate this as

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
    MyArray<T> array;
}
```

This is producing an error:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template<class T, template<class T> class Container> class MyArray'
MyArray<T> y;
```

And it points to the `>` of `MyArray<T>`.

What's wrong in this? Why can't I have a default template parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can address  `std::vector` without any template argument, have you tried `template <typename T, template <typename T> class Container = std::vector<T>>`?

Comment: @DavidHaim Actually this is possible and this is (as I think) not the source of the problem. Nevertheless, yes I tried that. Actually I'm starting to think that the problem is that I have to address the allocator template parameter of std::vector.

Comment: Also you'd better use something different than `T` in `template <typename T> class Container`, clang also warns about shadowing in this case.

Comment: @Predelnik Actually using `T` there is on purpose, because I want the template parameter of that to match with the first template parameter mentioned by the user. I hope this is not wrong, because I tried it a while ago (don't remember the details).

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist You want some template template parameter which is a class template with no template parameters specified, you specify them later in `class MyArray : Container<T>`, you may even remove that T to avoid confusion, it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: @Predelnik If I remove that `<T>` I would get an error `error: expected class-name before {`

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist `template <typename T, template <typename> class Container = std::vector> class MyArray : Container<T> {};` compiles fine for me.

Comment: @Predelnik Have you tried to instantiate an object out of that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `std::vector` takes two template arguments: the type and the allocator. Many other container types will takes additional policy arguments which have defaults to allow you to instantiate like `T<U>`.

In order to support this, you can say that your template template parameter should take *at least* one template parameter using variadic templates (`typename...`):

```
template <typename T, template <typename, typename...> class Container = std::vector>
class MyArray : Container<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer. Yes this starts to gloss the problem... but still not the full solution. I'm still getting an error at the the part `Container<T>`, where it says there should be there 2 arguments, and simply adding the allocator parameter that I mentioned in the template template parameter doesn't work.

Comment: you mean `template<class T, template<typename T, typename... Args> class MyArray : Container<T, Args...>`

Comment: @TemplateRex Yes, the Args part says that it's not declared in this scope (even though it's mentioned as you did in args).

Comment: @TartanLlama Please try to instantiate an object from that with `MyClass<double> myarray`.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Instantiating it like that [works for me](https://ideone.com/lvyYBK).

Comment: @TartanLlama I didn't get that the "dots" are literal. Please mention that in your answer. Thanks a lot this works!

Comment: @Angew we all make mistakes! :)

Comment: Yeah interestingly enough because of ellipsis it seems like it finds the default argument on second phase of look-up.